# I am trying to check the Multicollinearity between the variables using vif() in R to improve my Linear Regression Model

Tags: r, linear-regression

```
#install.packages("car")
library(car)

model1<-lm(Temp ~ . , data = climate) # all the independent variables are numeric.
summary(model1) # Proper output
vif(model1)
```

I get an error and a warning when I execute the the `vif(model1)`.

> Error in as.vector(y) - mean(y) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I have gone through similar queries in stackoverflow. Most of them suggested to install `car` package. I have done that still no luck.

> str(climate)

'data.frame':   308 obs. of  9 variables:

$ MEI     : num  2.556 2.167 1.741 1.13 0.428 ...

$ CO2     : num  346 346 344 342 340 ...

$ CH4     : num  1639 1634 1633 1631 1648 ...

$ N2O     : num  304 304 304 304 304 ...

$ CFC.11  : num  191 192 193 194 194 ...

$ CFC.12  : num  350 352 354 356 357 ...

$ TSI     : num  1366 1366 1366 1366 1366 ...

$ Aerosols: num  0.0863 0.0794 0.0731 0.0673 0.0619 0.0569 0.0524 0.0486 0.0451 0.0416 ...

$ Temp    : num  0.109 0.118 0.137 0.176 0.149 0.093 0.232 0.078 0.089 0.013 ...

Comment: Is temp numeric? Is temp a variable stored in climate, so that `climate$temp` does not return an error? If the answer is no to either of these, then this is probably the cause of the error. Please post the output of `str(climate)` at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Can you list your R version? Could be an empty model that you are running vif() on.  I can't see climate data in the data folder of the car package. Check d <- data(package = "car");d

Comment: @office206 R version 3.3.2

Comment: Couldn't help noticing: in the `str(climate)` output, `$Temp` is capitalized.

Comment: @MattTyers. A mistake in posting the question here. My actual code has Uppercase T. Il make changes in the question.
Thanks :)

Comment: You bet!  Was hoping the answer could just be that simple.